# rmarkdown - Files in shared folders not working

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm unable to see properly rmarkdown HTML outputs in a shared folder.

I'm generating a report using

```
rmarkdown::render('myfile.rmd')
```

The output HTML has images and DT::datatable. The file generated by render() works fine when I open it in my computer. If I send the HTML file by email to colleagues they can see it with no issues.

As soon as I copy the HTML file to a shared folder in a server, it is no longer rendered correctly: all DT::datatable's are missing and font's do not show correctly.

I tried also:

```
rmarkdown('myfile.rmd', output_dir = 'shared_folder/', output_file = 'myreport.html')
```

And this also does not work. The Rmd file is in my local computer, the output_dir is the shared folder. The file is written in the shared folder correctly, but when I try to open it I get the same issue as before.

Initially the webpage in the shared folder would crash Internet Explorer. I added mathjax:null option to the Rmd file and the crashing stopped, but the fonts/DT::datatable missing issues continued:

```
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: null
```

My local harddrive is NTFS, the shared folder file system is also NTFS.

The pandoc options shown by rmarkdown are (personal information suppressed):

```
+RTS -K512m -RTS myfile.utf8.md --to html 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
--output myfile.html 
--smart --email-obfuscation none 
--self-contained --standalone --section-divs 
--template "C:\Users\[...]\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" 
--no-highlight 
--variable highlightjs=1 
--variable "theme:simplex" 
--include-in-header "C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqm2YlA\rmarkdown-str18ab05327b00.html"
```

Running R 3.3.2 in Windows 7.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turns out it was na issue with permissions in Internet Explorer. When the HTML file was opened in Chrome it worked.

Comment: IE opens documents on shared drives\folders in compatibility mode.  You can override this behavior by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` to the head of the html file. Then your file should open just fine in IE.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have to manually add the tag in the head of the output HTML. When I try to use include in_header the tag is added after script tags and then the behavior is the same.

Comment: I have noticed that too.  I have some code for a work around I can post this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer opens files in shared drives and folders in compatibility mode.  You can over-ride this behavior by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` to the head of the HTML document.

However using the in_header YAML tag does not work.  I believe this is because Pandoc places these tags at the end of the header section and IE requires this tag fall earlier in the header.  To overcome this I use the following code to generate IE compatible files which will be stored and accessed from a network drive:

```
knitr::knit("myfile.rmd")
HtmlList <- readLines("myfile.html")
HtmlList[HtmlList == "<head>"] <- "<head> <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" />"

fileConn <- file("myfile.html")
writeLines(HtmlList, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```